# Attach a video stream onto an existing application

Tags: c++, winapi

Is it possible to show a video that is playing onto an existing application?

Application A is running.

Get Video A and place it on top of Application A and then play it.

Thanks! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to load a video and play it, you can use the [DirectShow API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783323.aspx), which will use the installed Windows codecs to attempt playback. You can also use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for a selection of codecs that may not be installed on the computer.